# Find duplicates within five columns

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have dataset from columns A to K and would like find duplicate rows of data from columns A, D, F, J and K.

I have the following code:

```
Sub RemoveDupes2()

Dim r As Long, lr As Long
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lr = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
   With Range("L2:L" & lr)
     .Formula = "=ROW()"
      .Value = .Value
   End With
  Range("A2:L" & lr).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=1, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=1
  With Range("M2:M" & lr)
   .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-11]&RC[-6]&RC[-4]&RC[-2]"
   .Value = .Value
    End With
  With Range("N2:N" & lr)
   .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R1C13:RC[-1],RC[-1])"
      .Value = .Value
  End With
    For r = lr To 2 Step -1
     If Cells(r, 14).Value > 2 Then
        Rows(r).Delete
     ElseIf Cells(r, 14).Value = 2 Then
      Cells(r - 1, 1).Resize(, 7).Font.Bold = True
      Rows(r).Delete
     End If
    Next r
    lr = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
      Range("A2:L" & lr).Sort Key1:=Range("L2"), Order1:=1
     Range("L2:N" & lr).ClearContents
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      End Sub
```

The code currently deletes the entire data set and I am not sure why its doing so, as I am novice user to VBA.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/otgkk1igcd2995t/duplicates.xlsx

Comment: what excel version are you running?

Comment: dear @ScottHoltzman, I am using excel version 2003.

Comment: Also, can you post a link to a sample sheet of your data (or dummy data), or tell me what kind of values column J has, because this statement `If Cells(r, 10).Value > 2 Then` maybe causing everything to delete if whatever is in column J is > 2 or it's a text value or something.

Comment: Dear @ScottHoltzman, I have updated the code, but now its re-arranging the data in alphabetical order and I ideally i would like to highlight columns A, D, F, J and K. Also, How can i post link to show sample of my dataset.  Thank you so much for your response and help.

Comment: you can use wwww.dropbox.com to send links to datasets.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3h3crbsf2u9j8q/duplicates.xlsx

Comment: for sorting, change last sort to this: `Range("A2:M" & lr).Sort Key1:=Range("M2"), Order1:=1`, that way you sort on your concatenated field before removing it.

Comment: The code above was ideally used to compare all the columns to find rows with duplicate data, I modified the code to only look in columns A, D, F, J and K, to find duplicate data only. However, it does not do that.  Instead the code rearranges the dataset and does not find all the duplicates. Thank you for your time and help with my problem.

Comment: see my last comment about how to sort. Make the change and the code should work. If you'd like I can post the code as an answer so you can see what I did in full, but it's really just a small change.

Comment: Dear @ScottHoltzman, thank you so much for your help. I manage to solve the sorting problem, which was due to code on line 9. However, the code is not idenfying the correct duplicate data.  How can I modify the code, so it only looks at rows of columns A, D, F, J and K, to identify duplicates rows of data. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I have provided an updated sample file, which shows desired output of the data and what the code is currently outputting use the above code.  Thank you so much for any help and assistant.https://www.dropbox.com/s/otgkk1igcd2995t/duplicates.xlsx

Comment: I looked at your sample, but the code seems to be doing exactly what you want. There was no "before" and "after" in the file, so unless you provide more clarity, it's hard to help.

Comment: rather than just running code and wondering why it's not doing what you want, set a break point at the start and start stepping!  Evaluate the values at each delete line to make sure it's calculating what you think it should be calculating.  Simplify your data set to a handful of rows to make life a bit easier (include a row you know should be deleted and a row you know shouldn't). A lot of times, what *should* be happening is COMPLETELY different than what *is* happening.  Don't blindly accept that your code is written to do what you want it do to!

Answer (score 0):

In your first `With`, please try changing:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-11]&RC[-6]&RC[-4]&RC[-2]"
```

to

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-9]&RC[-7]&RC[-3]&RC[-2]"
```

There may well however be a separate issue because even unaltered the above code does not delete the entire dataset (for me, with Excel 2007).